# Wordpress site: What is the flow to get MySQL data as a Javascript variable safely?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and I need to access data from one of my databases in some javascript/jquery.

Conceptually, what is the best way to do this? I considered installing a plugin to allow PHP in the Wordpress "Custom HTML Element", but would that be just as unsafe as accessing the MySQL database with Javascript? Should I make an event handling php script that lives elsewhere?

This will be used for user-specific sensitive data so it needs to be as secure as possible.

Not asking for any code, just not sure what a secure data flow would look like here. Thanks!

Comment: My main worry is that someone tinkering around with the code on the page could simply put in a different email in the right place for example and alter the output on the page to view another user's data.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a handy [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) that's pretty easy to extend. This is exactly what [API](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-is-an-api-in-english-please-b880a3214a82?gi=1bf4c1d08c87)s are for in general - accessing data stored on another domain. Remote MySQL connections are totally possible and sometimes necessary, but for simply display a little data, using or building a simple JSON API is often the preferred method.

Depending on what information you're adding/pulling via the API (either the native WP REST API, or custom one), you may want to authenticate the requests with a key of some sort - and it sounds like this is something you'll need to do based on your concerns of viewing data.

Using an API like the WP Rest api lets you get just about any information you want, typically as a [JSON](https://www.json.org/) string, which you can then display/modify with JavaScript, PHP, etc.